# how to get a post or get variable

Tags: php

I have an html form that depending on the checkbox my java-script change it from GET to POST.  This piece of code is currently working.

My question is I have a variable on the server side that I need to get. The html variable is sent either as POST or GET, but not sure how to retrieve that variable regardless or what method the html uses.  I know how to get the variable as either POST or GET manually, but Not sure how to go about accomplishing this automatically.  Any suggestions?

```
$myVariable = $_GET['htmlVariable'] or $myVariable = $_POST['htmlVariable']
```

Comment: What you're looking for is `$_REQUEST` https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use $_GET if you know that data is coming via URL parameter

```
if (isset($_GET['htmlVariable'] && $_GET['htmlVariable'] != '') {
  $htmlVariable = $_GET['htmlVariable'];
}
```

2) Use $_POST if you know that data is coming via HTTP POST method

```
if (isset($_POST['htmlVariable'] && $_POST['htmlVariable'] != '') {
    $htmlVariable = $_GET['htmlVariable'];
}
```

3) If you don't know use $_REQUEST

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['htmlVariable'] && $_REQUEST['htmlVariable'] != '') {
    $htmlVariable = $_GET['htmlVariable'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to check if *one* of the two methods is found. If it is, use that method, and if not, use the other method. To achieve this you can use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), and note that you'll also want to check that the string isn't empty:

```
if (isset($_GET['htmlVariable'] && $_GET['htmlVariable'] != '') {
  $myVariable = $_GET['htmlVariable'];
}
else if (isset($_POST['htmlVariable'] && $_POST['htmlVariable'] != '') {
  $myVariable = $_POST['htmlVariable'];
}
else {
  $myVariable = 'something else';
}
```

Also note that the order in which you check for the methods may make a difference, depending on your logic.

Comment: Why all that complexity, why don't you just use `$myVariable = $_GET['htmlVariable'] ?? $_POST['htmlVariable'] ?? 'something else';`

Comment: @Kerkouch Because that is valid only in PHP 7.0+. Not necessarily the case...

Answer (score 0):

If you are building any page that may require either input type, instead of trying to determine what is being provided, just use $_REQUEST.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['htmlVariable'] && $_REQUEST['htmlVariable'] != '') {
    $htmlVariable = $_REQUEST['htmlVariable'];
```

}

Comment: @Obsidian Age gave me the answer I was looking for, but incorrectly sets the $htmlVariable to $_GET in each example and I don't have enough points to comment on his answer to point that out. Kerkouch also give the correct answer but only as a comment.